# using didSelectItem for programmed UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, button, uicollectionview, segue, swift4

I have programmed a UICollectionView and when the cell is select I would like for it to go to another view cotroller. I am getting the error message of

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "twoVC") as? twoVC

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
        //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value     
    }

}

class twoVC : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var label : UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var photo : UIImageView!

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are force unwrapping `vc` so chances are that it is `nil` which means that likely `"twoVC"` is not the identifier for that view controller in the storyboard. Double check that in your storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Yep, agreed with Andy here, it's probably an ID issue

Comment: great pic @GilSand !

Comment: you mean my profile picture haha ? Thanks ! But it has nothing special ^^

Comment: Your right I forget it. But I added it and still the same error pops up.  This is the only storyboard I have and the storyboard file is called Storyboard.storyboard. @AndyObusek

Comment: Is the `storyboard` property setup correctly because if that is nil then you `vc` will also be nil leading to this error.  Put a break point on the line where you are pushing the view controller onto the navigation controller and run in the debugger to inspect the values of everything and see what is causing the problem.